# Group data with Crystal Reports 13

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I've been trying to group data in a crystal report for two days and I just can't make it work.

What I'm trying to accomplish is grouping comments based on their user category.

I have this data:

```
Question Nr Answer Category

oq1         asdf   External
oq1         Hej    Manager
oq1         asdf   External
```

And I want this to be shown as:

**QuestionNr**

**External**
asdf
asdf

**Manager**
Hej

I've been trying what feels like a million different group combinations but it just won't do what I want. The closest I've come is this:

**QuestionNr**

**External**

asdf

**Manager**

hej

**External**

asdf

Does anyone know of a solution that would work?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: You are grouping correctly, the data must be dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Group1 should be questionnr and group2 should be category.

There is no reason the two asdf entries shouldn't be grouping together from what i can see- unless maybe there is some whitespace next to one of them?

Comment: Think my data was dirty, tried pulling a report for another user and it worked.